# Parallel Edge detection/handling not working on mxGraph at all

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am having some trouble with mxGraph and parallel edges. My understanding that the parallelEdgeLayout is supposed to find edges between two vertices, and if they overlap, add a spacing. However, I cannot get this to work at all.

I have my vertex and edge styles defined here:

```
GraphManager.prototype.defineStyles = function () {

    // Vertices
    style = new Object();
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTFAMILY] = "Salesforce Sans";
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mxConstants.SHAPE_RECTANGLE;    
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FOLDABLE] = 0;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ARCSIZE] = 9;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR] = "#A6B8CE";
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = "#7591b3";//original
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKEWIDTH] = 1;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER] = mxPerimeter.RectanglePerimeter;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER_SPACING] = 2;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHADOW] = false;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ORTHOGONAL] = true;
    this.graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle(styles.step, style);

    // Edges
    var style = new Object();
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE] = mxEdgeStyle.OrthConnector;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTFAMILY] = "Salesforce Sans";
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKEWIDTH] = 3;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_OPACITY] = 75;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_SOURCE_PERIMETER_SPACING] = 5;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_TARGET_PERIMETER_SPACING] = 5;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_JETTY_SIZE] = 'auto';
    this.graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle(styles.edge, style);
}
```

Then I set up my graph layout. I am using the stackLayout for the main layout of the graph. I have swim lanes set up that are stacked next to each other, and the stackLayout is the only layout that formats these correctly, so would like to use it.

```
GraphManager.prototype.defineLayout = function (model) {
    // Applies size changes to siblings and parents
    new mxSwimlaneManager(this.graph, false);

    var parallelEdgeLayout = new mxParallelEdgeLayout(this.graph);

    // Creates a stack depending on the orientation of the swimlane
    var layout = new mxStackLayout(this.graph);
    // Makes sure all children fit into the parent swimlane
    layout.resizeParent = true;

    // Applies the size to children if parent size changes
    layout.fill = true;

    // Only update the size of swimlanes
    layout.isVertexIgnored = function (vertex) {
        return !this.graph.isSwimlane(vertex);
    }

    // Keeps the lanes and pools stacked
    var layoutMgr = new mxLayoutManager(this.graph);

    layoutMgr.getLayout = function (cell) {
        if (!model.isEdge(cell) && this.graph.getModel().getChildCount(cell) > 0 &&
            (model.getParent(cell) == model.getRoot() || 
            this.graph.isPool(cell))) {
                layout.fill = this.graph.isPool(cell);

                return layout;
        }
    };


    this.graph.addListener(mxEvent.CELL_CONNECTED, function(sender, evt)
    {
        console.log('Getting Parallels');
        //var model = graph.getModel();
        var edge = evt.getProperty('edge');
        var src = model.getTerminal(edge, true);
        var trg = model.getTerminal(edge, false);

        console.log(src);
        console.log(trg);
        console.log(parallelEdgeLayout.findParallels(src));
        console.log(parallelEdgeLayout.findParallels(trg));

        parallelEdgeLayout.isEdgeIgnored = function(edge2)
        {
            var src2 = model.getTerminal(edge2, true);
            var trg2 = model.getTerminal(edge2, false);

            return !(model.isEdge(edge2) && ((src == src2 && trg == trg2) || (src == trg2 && trg == src2)));
        };

        parallelEdgeLayout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
    });
}
```

I have tried using a compositeLayout with stack layout and parallel edge layout, that didn't work either. The approach above does not work. in the console.logs for my cell connected listener, it will not detect any parallel edges between any vertices even though from this picture:

[image]

There are definitely parallel edges... I would greatly appreciate any insight on getting parallel edge handling running on mxGraph. It would be nice to have the graph be able to sort this out on its own. Otherwise, I am going to have to calculate out all the exit and entry points for my edges on vertices, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for running the parallel edge layout:

```
var graph = new mxGraph(container);
var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
try
{
    var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello,', 20, 20, 80, 30);
    var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'World!', 200, 150, 80, 30);
    var e1 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', v1, v2);
    var e2 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', v2, v1);
}
finally
{
    graph.getModel().endUpdate();
}

var layout = new mxParallelEdgeLayout(graph);
layout.execute(parent);
```